# What should I do when receiving error notifications by the system

Tags: error-handling

I am often getting the message:

> Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error. If you notice
>   further problems, try restarting the computer.

I am worried about my system stability.

What have I done that may cause this problem? Is it my fault? What can I do to solve this issue?